# Is there a way to un-enqueue a WordPress plugin's script within functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wp-enqueue-scripts

A plugin vendor I'm getting support from recently suggested that if I didn't want a certain Javascript file within the plugin to be enqueued, I should go into the plugin's files and comment out the enqueueing. However, this will potentially have to be repeated each time I update the plugin. Is there a way to un-enqueue a plugin's script from functions.php in my child theme so that the change will "stick"?

Comment: If you know the handle of the script you could try using the [wp_dequeue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/) function -which is what "intertainment for you" below seems to be suggesting- to remove it. However, if the plugin uses OOP code then it might be a little more difficult. You'd need to provide more details so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, the native WordPress function is called `wp_dequeue_script`.

> Remove a previously enqueued script.

@see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/

### Example

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
} );
```

Comment: This should work, but it looks like the plugin developer did not provide a proper handle to reference. I've decided to report the issue to the developer and wait for them to update their plugin to include a handle.

Answer (score -2):

```
function wp_dequeue_script( $handle ) {
    _wp_scripts_maybe_doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, $handle );
 
    wp_scripts()->dequeue( $handle );
}
```

Comment: You can't re-register a native function.

Comment: Remove a previously enqueued script.
@see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/

add_action( 'init', function () {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
} );

Comment: The code copied in this documentation is what the `wp_dequeue_script()` function *does*, not what you should write in order to make it work. Adding this code to your `functions.php` file will result in errors because this function already exists.